# regex to replace contend of second <p>-tag

Tags: php, regex

Output (var $DESC)

```
 <p>erster Absatz</p>
 <p>zweiter Absatz</p>
```

Regex (PHP)

```
 preg_replace("<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>{2}", '', $DESC)
```

I would like to delete only the second p but this regex finds both. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Will it always be a `<p>` block followed immediately by another `<p>` block, or does it need to check for any element that occurs twice in a row?

Comment: thanks - it will be always like this p-block followed by another p-block

Comment: You really should use an HTML parser for this...

Comment: Also, I didn't vote your question down, but I know why others did. Using regex to parse HTML (and other non-regular languages) is highly discouraged https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: whats a better solution? I got this string through a feed, cannot change anything there and I don't need the second p block..

Comment: Assuming you can't use an HTML parser (for whatever reason, even though you're using PHP and that's **exactly** how you should approach this), you can use this `<p>(.*?)<\/p>` and grab the second result from your `preg_match_all`. But again, I would **highly discourage using regex for this**

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would just tell you to use an HTML parser instead of regex, but since your requirement is so specific, this can actually be accomplished with regex quite safely.

`(?<=<\/p>)\s+<p>[\w ]+<\/p>`

https://regex101.com/r/Yqaajy/6

Explanation:

`(?<=<\/p>)` - Make sure the rest of the pattern is preceded by a `<\p>` ending tag (positive lookbehind).

`\s+` - Any number of whitespace characters. Note that this will not match correctly if you have single line mode enabled.

`<p>[\w ]+<\/p>` - A paragraph block containing one or more word characters (digits, letters, and underscore) and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$DESC ='<p>erster Absatz</p>
 <p>zweiter Absatz</p>';

$DESC = preg_replace('#\</p\>[^\<]*\<p[^\>]*\>(.*?)\</p\>#i', '</p>', $DESC);
echo $DESC; // <p>erster Absatz</p>
```